# How can I revert a jquery draggable object after drop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Can you tell me please how can I revert the position of a draggable object after been dropped ?

<strike>$(".draggable").draggable({revert: "invalid"});</strike>

is not what I want. I want that the droppable reverts the draggable after the drop event, not the draggable reverts itself to its initial position after drop event. (Sorry for my bad english).

I want that because I have two droppable and one draggable. The first droppable removes the draggable and the second droppable displays more information about the draggable. After that, the draggable reverts to its initial position.

Thank you !

Comment: You have to do it manually: save the `originalPosition` the first time you drop the `draggable` and then `animate()` it there whenever you want to. Try to make an example, then could give more specific help if you're having trouble with it

Comment: I'm on it. Thank you !